# How to increment counter in a transaction in Firestore Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am following an example of transactions identical to the documentation of Firebase Android.

But the code is executed many times, making the counter increment several times, but would have to increment only once.

```
final DocumentReference produtosRef = db.collection("Produtos").document(produtoSelecionado.getKey());

    db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
            DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(produtosRef);
            if(snapshot.exists()){
                Produto produto = snapshot.toObject(Produto.class);
                String key = snapshot.getId();
                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                childUpdates.put("quantidadeItensEstoque",produto.getQuantidadeItensEstoque() + compra_x_produto.getQuantidadeComprado());
                childUpdates.put("precoVenda", compra_x_produto.getPrecoVendaProduto());
                produtosRef.update(childUpdates);
                // Success
                return null;
            }else{
                // se nao tiver nenhum item ainda desse produto so faz o update
                String key = snapshot.getId();
                Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                childUpdates.put("quantidadeItensEstoque",  compra_x_produto.getQuantidadeComprado());
                childUpdates.put("precoVenda", compra_x_produto.getPrecoVendaProduto());

                produtosRef.update(childUpdates);
                LoadingUtil.hideLoading();
                // Success
                return null;
            }
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Transaction success!");
        }
    })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failure.", e);
                }
            });
```

Comment: "the code is executed many times" how many?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a transaction in order to increment a counter in a Cloud Firestore database. You can increment your counter with the use of FieldValue's [increment()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html#increment(long)) method, which will help you incrementing values atomically:

```
FieldValue.increment(yourNumber);
```

> Returns a special value that can be used with the set() or update() that tells the server to increment the field's current value by the given value.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It also does not help if the transaction doesn't read in the document with the field that is being incremented.

Comment: You've given an alternative to the question asked, but not answered the original question. Your answer may be a solution to the problem, but it does not answer the question. I personally have a situation where I want to update 2 documents with a transaction, but I'd prefer not to have to do the read roundtrip just to increment. By not answering the question, you've made the question less useful for future readers. Now I'm required to ask again with the same title.

It seems there is no way to do what I want as of now, which is a fine answer to the question.

Comment: increment will work in case where it maybe thousands of users incrementing same value in firestore. Ideally I just want to have counter increment to thousand as thousand users are trying to increment it. Will it work that way?

Comment: @AnkitMishra Yes, it will. It's an atomic operation.